# Represent the following propositions using quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Domain: x and y are in the domain of all people
V(x, y): "x has venmoed money to y"

a) "Jake has not venmoed money to Lauren"

b) "There are at least two kids who have not venmoed each other"

c) "Everyone has venmoed the same person" (the person is not themselves)

My answers:

a) ∀x∀y[~V(Jake, Lauren)]

b) ∃x∃y[~V(x,y)] | (x != y)

c) ∀x∃y[V(x,y)] | (x != y)

I am really unsure about my first answer, because I have to use logic and predicates to modify the domain. I am not allowed to actually manipulate the domain.

Are my answers correct?

Answer (score 1):

> > a) "Jake has not venmoed money to Lauren"
>
> a) ∀x∀y[~V(Jake, Lauren)]

Nope. The only variables in this statement are the constants.  You do not need quantifiers. $$\lnot\mathsf V(\textrm{Jake}, \textrm{Lauren})$$

> > b) "There are at least two kids who have not venmoed each other"
>
> b) ∃x∃y[~V(x,y)] | (x != y)

N... Well... the $\mid$ symbol is typically used for 'or', while $\&$ is used for 'and'. You need to say that there are two who are not the same *and* one of them did not venmo the other, so check your symbols.

$$\exists x\exists y~(x\neq y\mathop{\&} \lnot\mathsf V(x,y))$$

$\tiny\textrm{Well the immediate translation is $\exists x\exists y~(x\neq y\mathop{\&} (\lnot\mathsf V(x,y))\mid \lnot\mathsf V(y,x)))$ however, the above is an equivalent rephrasing.}$

> c) "Everyone has venmoed the same person" (the person is not themselves)
>
> c) ∀x∃y[V(x,y)] | (x != y)

"There is someone whom *everyone else* had venmoed."  To refer to the *same* existance, the existential must be bound before the universal.

$$\exists y~\forall x~(x\neq y\to\mathsf V(x,y))$$